# Number with no decimal mark

Tags: number-representation

I'm using *Mathematica* to create some images and labeling them after a simple calculation done previously. As the name of the file depends on the result, I want to show it with no decimal separator (because the "." can be a program as I'll use these images later on LabView). I'm using the following code:

`ang = NumberForm[N[frac], {5, 2}]`

where the result has 5 precise digits and 2 digits to the right of the decimal. Then, I'm doing `angle = ang*100`, but I still get the decimal marker but no number after it. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question: When you want to use this in the file name, why don't you use another character as `NumberPoint`?

```
ToString[NumberForm[N[8/3], {5, 2}, NumberPoint -> "_"]]

(* "2_67" *)
```

This can easily be included into a file name without problems.

To answer your question I have to start again with another question: Is there a special reason why you don't multiply by 100 and just round the result? (if you don't want it as `String` just remove the first function)

```
IntegerString[Round[N[8/3]*100]]

(* "267" *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Using `_` as a decimal separator is a great suggestion and the `Round[]` solution is what I wanted.